# path integrals using different closed paths in $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this question the other day and I don't really understand how to do it!

Let $f(z)=(5z^2-8)/(z^3-2z^2)$. Determine the integral of $f(z)$ over $gamma(0,1)$ the unit circle.

Then describe different closed paths in **C** such that the above integral equals $14*pi*i, 18*pi*i and -2*pi*i$.

I have tried making a substitution $z=exp(i*theta)$ for actually calculating the integral, but it always gets very messy and I end up with things that I can't integrate, so could someone show me how to do this please!

For the second part, I think I need to consider how many times the closed curve spirals round, but I don't know how to come up with explicit examples.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hints** :

Try to write $f$ as $z\mapsto \dfrac{g(z)}{z^2}$ and use 
[Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) to find that $\displaystyle\oint_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z=i\pi g'(0)$.

Be careful that $g$ verifies the right hypotheses.

Besides the derivative of $g$, you almost have nothing to calculate here (no parametrization is needed for example). For the other integrals, you just have to choose paths carefully.

Comment: I can't manage to get the $z^2$ out of the denominator so I'm struggling to use Cauchy's integral formula, any advice?

Comment: Write $f(z)=g(z)/z^2$ then apply Cauchy's integral formula to $g$.

Comment: but your first statement should read $z^3-2z^2=z(z^2-2z)$ .

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: no worries, I take it that method is still valid if I try it then>

Comment: cheers, will work on the first part. are my thoughts correct regarding the second part?

Comment: Yes, the winding number is important if you want to  multiply the value of your integral by an integer. You also have to avoid certain poles of $f$ inside the contour (only one to use Cauchy's formula). You can also use the residue theorem if needed.